# How would I consume the body of a put request from a web worker

Tags: javascript, http, request, service-worker, put

I want to consume data sent through a put request in a web worker. How would I do so?

this the part in my code where I am trying to handle the put request

```js
if (method === 'put') {
    var request = event.request;
    //how would I turn the request object into an array buffer?
}
```

Comment: Just use the [request's `body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/body)? You can also parse it into a `.text()` or `.json()` or [`.arrayBuffer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/arrayBuffer).

Comment: If you add that as and answer I can accept it

Comment: I just was confused because you had deleted your own answer that was stating essentially the same thing, so I wondered if there was something else you'd need

Comment: Yeah, thing was my answer seemed to stop working and would return undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consume the [request's body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/body) as an array buffer using the [`.arrayBuffer()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/arrayBuffer).